# Change ownership of vagrant homestead directory

Tags: magento, vagrant, homestead, magento2

I'm trying to install Magento 2 on a homestead environment and The only sticking block I've hie is one of the requirements for file ownership

> The owner of the Magento file system:
>
> Must have full control (read/write/execute) of all files and directories.
>
> Must not be the web server user; it should be a different user.

Is it possible with homestead to change the ownership of a site? I've been searching google fanatically trying to find anyone who has mentioned it and the only result i found is someone mentioning this same quote from Magento themselves while they were trying to run Magento 2 on Homestead, though they never mentioned how they solved the issue.

I tried setting up a new user manually as I would on CentOS with sudo on the vagrant user, but when trying to run chown on the files they don't change from vagrant:vagrant

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity over 5000 questions tagged vagrant none of which seem to be about programming

Comment: This is a programming Q&A site. They all should have been closed if they're not specifically about programming. The help center says that to be on-topic the question must be "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: It's also worth noting that what is "off topic" changes semi-regularly on Stackoverflow. What was on topic years ago may not be now and is also open to being closed or migrated to a more relevant StackExchange site.